# Who holds core Country > IP data?

Tags: routing, ip, ipv6, ip-routing

** Please note I am not after an online conversion provider **

Where does the source data come for an IP > Country lookup? For example the WHOIS database has a Country flag but it cannot be relied upon. Where is the source for the connection?

Is it a case that 123.x.x.x always points to Asia, 123.123.x.x always points to Japan etc?

Additionally what about IP6 addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main repository is at IANA: https://www.iana.org/numbers.

You then have more *local* regions for:

- Africa: http://www.afrinic.net/
- Asia/Pacific: https://www.apnic.net/
- (most of) North America: https://www.arin.net/
- Latin America: http://www.lacnic.net/
- Europa, Middle East and Central Asia: https://www.ripe.net/

More granular data is handled by the ISPs.

Comment: And no, you cannot say 123.x.x.x always points to asia and 123.123.x.x always points to japan, because subnets are bought by companies and those can route it anywhere over the net pretty easily.

Comment: The only blocks unlikely to move are IPv6 blocks.